# Mapping Magento Test Automation Framework suite to netbeans

Tags: magento2.2

I am unable to integrate the MTAF in netbeans. Can you please provide me some ideas ,how to map to netbeans.
My MTAF folder structure:
[image]

and netbeans configuration folder structure steps:

1. open netbeans click on FILE->NEWPROJECT->PHP->PHP APPLICATION WITH EXISTING SOURCES->CLICk.
2. Source folder(path to magento folder)
3. Run AS:"script in command line"-->PHP Interpreter

**once I click on the  Projects window, right-click the node for your project and select "Properties". On the 'Sources' tab: In the 'Test Folder' field, set the path to the folder with tests.** (I am unable to find the "Testfolder")

Please help with this or Tell me another procedure to map the magento test framework.

[image])

[image]
 [image]

[image]